# Retrieving values from an API call | Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

I am using an API to GET the currency rates. The base & output currency are being entered by the user.

This is my Backend:

```
    import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';  


export function getCurrency(currency,baseCurrency) {
    const url = 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=';

    let fullUrl = url + baseCurrency + '&symbols=' + currency;

    return fetch(fullUrl, {method: 'get'})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => json.rates[currency].toString());
}
```

And This is my Page Code:

```
    import {getCurrentTemp, getCurrency} from 'backend/ArenaApi';

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
    getCurrency($w("#currencysymbol").value,$w("#baseCurrency").value)
  .then(rates => $w("#currencyrate").text = "1 " + ($w("#baseCurrency").value) + " = " + rates + " " + ($w("#currencysymbol").value));
    $w("#currencyrate").show();
}
```

From what I understand my Backend is getting this data:

```
"base":"USD","date":"2018-05-22","rates":{"EUR":0.84789}
```

and it is retrieving the **"rates"** from this string via the following line in the backend:

```
.then(json => json.rates[currency].toString());
```

I want to know how can I retrieve multiple values from a single string ? For this instance: **"rates"** **"base"** **"date"** and then inject it into a text element in the page like:

```
.then(rates => $w("#currencyrate").text = "1 " + ($w("#baseCurrency").value) + " = " + rates + " " + ($w("#currencysymbol").value));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by returning the entire JSON to the page code, instead of just the rates in you backend code:

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';  

export function getCurrency(currency,baseCurrency) {
  const url = 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=';
  let fullUrl = url + baseCurrency + '&symbols=' + currency;

  return fetch(fullUrl, {method: 'get'})
    .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Now that you have everything available to the page code, you can pull whatever you want from it. For example:

```
import {getCurrentTemp, getCurrency} from 'backend/ArenaApi';

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
  const currency = $w("#currencysymbol").value;
  const baseCurrency = $w("#baseCurrency").value;

  getCurrency(currency, baseCurrency)
    .then( (json) => {
      $w("#base").text = json.base;
      $w("#date").text = json.date;
      $w("#rate").text = json.rates[currency].toString 
    });
```

}

Comment: Its throwing an error for 'currency' undefined     ** $w("#rate").text = json.rates[currency].toString**